# The tablix ‘Tablix1’ has an incorrect number of TablixCornerCell.

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

`An error occurred during local report processing`

The number of `TablixCornerCell within TablixCornerRow` at `index: 0` must equal the number of levels in the TablixRowHierarchy containing TablixHeaders.

Comment: Try rebuild (not build) the solution

Answer (score 1):

I got this error message after deleting a row group from a tablix by simply removing the row itself

I didn't realise that in doing so I had left an extra 'orphaned' column within the table - when I removed the leftover column then the error disappeared.

Next time I will use the Groups pane to delete the row group, and tick the 'remove rows/columns associated with the group' button

Answer (score 0):

The reason I got this error when deleting the lowest group of the matrix (SSRS 2008) was because of merged rows above the row representing the group I was deleting.

So after splitting all the cells you can first delete the last column in the “row sector” of the matrix and then delete the group and row with no problems.